# Disallow access to browser security setting - Use Secure DNS

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dns, browser, administration

I am looking to set up parental controls across my Windows machines and at the network level.

As part of this step, I had already established restrictions at the router level through a custom DNS.

This configuration works well for all of my machines for most of my needs.

However, I have discovered that *Chromium* browsers have a feature (*DNS over HTTPS*) where we can configure a specific DNS of our choice

[image: Chrome Setting - Use secure DNS - currently enabled]

When enabled with an alternate DNS chosen from among the list, this ***overrides*** my network level DNS configuration within the browser instance.

Now, I would like to ***disable*** toggling on/off this setting (**greying out**), so that this feature cannot be used.

This question is solely raised to help workaround this specific problem.
Assume that *VPNs* cannot be used as the community here may suggest it.

Comment: If your children know this much about computers, then nothing will help. But you may try [How to Protect Your Child Online With Microsoft Family Safety](https://www.makeuseof.com/microsoft-family-safety-limit-childs-pc-usage/).

Comment: You can disable this option by enabling the applicable [Chromium Group Policy](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates/). [Use built-in DNS client](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::BuiltInDnsClientEnabled)